# Cannot use list in lazycolumn in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

I am using LazyColumn in project. When I am passing the list it giving me error. Can someone guide me what is the error?

**[ResultScreen.kt](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/ResultScreen.kt)**

```
@Composable
fun ResultScreen(nearestResultList: List<NearestResult>?) {
    LazyColumn(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(getBackgroundColor())
    ) {
        items(nearestResultList) { nearestResult ->
            Text(text = "$nearestResult")
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Int
Found:
List<NearestResult>?
```

[image]

UPDATE

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were seeing that error because your `nearestResultList` is nullable and among the various signatures/overloads of the `items(...)` function, the signature `items(size: Int, ...)` was chosen as the "closest match".

The only thing that you need to do, to be able to use any of the `items(...)` signatures is a null check

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items // or auto-fix imports

if (nearestResultList != null) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(nearestResultList) {
            Text(text = it.event, color = Color.White)
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73072904/11560810). Thanks

Answer (score 27):

The correct solution is to use this import:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```

The problem is that the items function that accepts a list is defined as an Extension function, so we need to import it to make it visible for use.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Composable
fun ResultScreen(nearestResultList: List<NearestResult>?) {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(getBackgroundColor())
    ) {
        LazyColumn {
            nearestResultList?.size?.let {
                items(it) { index ->
                    Text(text = nearestResultList[index].event, color = Color.White)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those, who may use the Paging library, add

```
import androidx.paging.compose.items
```

Comment: I am facing issue in resolving this import statement. I am using `implementation "androidx.paging:paging-compose:3.2.1"` in my app level `build.gradle` file. So is there anything I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this issues a LazyHorizontalGrid, make sure you're importing:

import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.items

If you're seeing this issues a LazyRow, make sure you're importing:

import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items

Answer (score 0):

**Updated solution**

```
         LazyColumn {nearestResultList.isNotEmpty() -> {
                items(
                    count = nearestResultList.itemCount,
                    key = nearestResultList.itemKey(),
                    contentType = nearestResultList.itemContentType(
                    )
                ) { index ->
                    val item = nearestResultList[index]
                    if (item == null) {
                       //handle
                    } else {
                        Text(text = it.event, color = Color.White)
                    }
                }
            }}
```