# Backhandler not working in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Hey I am using BackHandler from this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69151539/11560810). When I am pressing back button it's not working. Can someone guide me on this.

[**ResultScreen.kt**](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/ResultScreen.kt)

```
@Composable
fun ResultScreen(navController: NavHostController, nearestResultList: List<NearestResult>?) {
    SportsResultTheme {
        MainScaffold {
            BackHandler {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
            LazyColumn {
                if (nearestResultList != null) {
                    items(nearestResultList) { nearestResult ->
                        Text(
                            text = nearestResult.event
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[**NavigationGraph.kt**](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/navigation/NavigationGraph.kt)

```
@Composable
internal fun NavigationGraph() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
        composable(ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
            SetupMainActivityView { nearestResult ->
                val nearestResultJson = Uri.encode(Json.encodeToString(nearestResult))
                navController.navigate(ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/$nearestResultJson")
            }
        }

        composable(
            ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/{$NEAREST_RESULT_JSON}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(NEAREST_RESULT_JSON) { type = NearestResultParamType() }
            )
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            ResultScreen(navController, backStackEntry.arguments?.getParcelableArrayList(NEAREST_RESULT_JSON))
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see more please visit my [repository](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult).

**UPDATE**

You can see my video [link](https://youtube.com/shorts/B9WfZt1VHhI?feature=share). Anyone know when I back press why my scren flicks ?

**UPDATE 2**

I added splash screen in my navigation

```
@Composable
internal fun NavigationGraph() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = ScreenRoute.Splash.route) {

        composable(route = ScreenRoute.Splash.route) {
            SplashScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
            SetupMainActivityView { nearestResult ->
                val nearestResultJson = Uri.encode(Json.encodeToString(nearestResult))
                navController.navigate(ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/$nearestResultJson") {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }
            }
        }

        composable(
            ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/{$NEAREST_RESULT_JSON}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(NEAREST_RESULT_JSON) { type = NearestResultParamType() }
            )
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            ResultScreen(navController, backStackEntry.arguments?.getParcelableArrayList(NEAREST_RESULT_JSON))
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
navController.navigate(ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/$nearestResultJson") {
                    popUpTo(ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }
```

Back is not working when I added splash screen

**UPDATE 4**

```
@Composable
internal fun NavigationGraph() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    var home by remember {
        mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
    }
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = home ?: ScreenRoute.Splash.route) {

        composable(route = ScreenRoute.Splash.route) {
            home = ScreenRoute.Home.route
            SplashScreen(navController = navController)
        }

        composable(ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
            SetupMainActivityView { nearestResult ->
                val nearestResultJson = Uri.encode(Json.encodeToString(nearestResult))
                navController.navigate(ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/$nearestResultJson") {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }
            }
        }

        composable(
            ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/{$NEAREST_RESULT_JSON}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(NEAREST_RESULT_JSON) { type = NearestResultParamType() }
            )
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            ResultScreen(navController, backStackEntry.arguments?.getParcelableArrayList(NEAREST_RESULT_JSON))
        }
    }
}
```

My splash screen not working when initial application load. It direct open my home screen after going to result screen back button again not working.

Comment: Is the backstack empty in this scenario? If it is, then `popBackStack()` only checks `if(backQueue.isEmpty())` and retuns `false`.

Comment: How should I know backQueue?

Comment: No I am asking, did you navigate already inside your app and then back is not working, or is it not working on the first destination? Because in the beginning the backstack will be empty so `popBackStack()` cannot navigate back. In that case it is working as intended.

Comment: yes I navigate already inside is not working.

Comment: First destination is working correctly, If I press back it close the application. But inside the the app is not working.

Comment: Could it be that your `SetupMainActivityView` screen immediately navigates forward again after the backstack has been popped? check if [this line](https://github.com/vivek-modi/SportsResult/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vivek/sportsresult/ui/screen/MainActivity.kt#L95) is executed again after you press the back button

Comment: @AdrianK yes when I debug the line is executed again. so what the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

try `navController.navigateUp()`
probably the stack has many entries, try using singleton navigation to that  stack is not full of undesired entries like

```
navController.navigate("destination") {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }
```

try to use dynamic start destination like

```
var home by remember {
        mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
    }
NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = home?:"splash_destination",
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
composable("splash) {
            home = "home_destination"
          ....
        }
.....
}
```

then go with previous approach

Comment: nothing working..

Comment: probably the stack has many entries, try using singleton navigation to that  stack is not full of undesired entries like navController.navigate("destination") {
                    popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }

Comment: can you explain me what is doing?

Comment: it's working fine. I want to learn whats is `saveState`, `launchSingleTop` , `restoreState` is doing?

Comment: saveState, save the ui state of the current screen, when navigating to other screen, such as rememberScrollState(), launchSingleTop  for making sure only one copy of this destination is available on backstack, restoreState for restoring the stored ui state

Comment: One another question

Comment: I added my splash screen, so my home screen is second so how can i replace `navController.graph.findStartDestination().id` because after adding splash screen when I press back it showing me splash screen then home screen.

Comment: Can you please guide me on this I tried `navController.graph[ScreenRoute.Home.route].id` is not working..

Comment: try then  popUpTo("destination") {
                        saveState = true
                    } where destination is the route to screen you want to navigate to after backpress

Comment: `navController.navigate(ScreenRoute.Result.route + "/$nearestResultJson") {
                    popUpTo(ScreenRoute.Home.route) {
                        saveState = true
                    }
                    launchSingleTop = true
                    restoreState = true
                }`

Comment: I tried this but not working

Comment: please see UPDATE 2 and UPDATE 3 section

Comment: try edited one which has dynamic start destination

Comment: no it's not working..

Comment: Sorry but it's not working please have a look on UPDATE 4 section.

Comment: try to learn from navigation codelab probably you may get more concepts on how navigation compose works https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-navigation

Comment: @vivekmodi do your homework before asking lot of questions in a single thread

Answer (score -1):

The **BackHandler** was not working may be because you were overriding the `onBackPressed` function in your `activity`.